# Is there a way to force qualification with module name for global members?

Tags: vba, excel

In a VBA module, say `mdlModule`, I can prevent a member (`Sub`, `Function` or variable), say `SomeMember`, from being globally visible from the outside by marking it as `Private`.

If I want to expose the member externally I mark it `Public` and I can access it through `mdlModule.SomeMember`.

The issue is that I can also access it directly with `SomeMember` which quickly creates a bunch of globally visible names.

Is there a way to **force scoping** of the globally visible member so that `SomeMember` would not be valid to call it, but only `mdlModule.SomeMember`?

Could I do that with **class modules** maybe?

Comment: Yes, you'd need a class.

Comment: @Rory Thanks for your quick answer. Can I expect an experience similar to standard modules and safely move to them or is there some limitations I should be aware of? Thanks.

Comment: @Rory To be more specific I'd need some kind of "static" methods. But IIRC this is not possible with class modules. I hope I'm wrong...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "static"? It is possible to create Static routines in class modules. As an aside, why exactly is this a problem for you?

Comment: "static" ("shared" in VB.Net) means the member can be accessed without an instance of the class: `MyClass.MyMember` instead of `Dim myInstance As New MyClass ... myInstance.MyMember`.

Comment: So the "problem" is that you need additional useless code to invoke the member. :)

Comment: I mean what is the problem with the original module access (which requires **less** code)

Comment: The "problem" with the default behaviour of modules is that you clutter the global scope with plenty of names. Moreover I fear there is a risk of conflict so I'd like to force users of my API to be clean and fully-qualify the names of the members they use. So this is not a blocking issue at all, just code quality. If a default module is the best I can do then I'll go for it. Thanks. :-)

Comment: What possible conflict could there be?

Comment: Say `module1` have Sub `Run`. User calls it with `Run()` and all is working fine. Later it imports an other module `module2` with a `Run` Sub too. The user code is broken as there is a conflict and it will see it only when compiling or running its previous code. Worst: without noticing the new Sub, the user removes `module1` (by mistake or deliberately) and it will inadvertently calls `Run` from `module2`. I imagine there is worse cases but you get the idea. :-/

Comment: That's not really API in any way. :) Users shouldn't be messing around with **your** code - that should be in a separate library, IMO.

Comment: You mean packaged as a protected XLA? AFAIK it won't avoid conflicts as what is public is still directly accessible without names qualification. But I may be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Type` or `Class`.

> Declare type in standard module

```
Public Type SomeType
    SomeMember As String
End Type
```

---

> Declare class in class module named *SomeClass*

```
Private m_someMember As String

Public Property Get SomeMember() As String
    SomeMember = m_someMember
End Property

Public Property Let SomeMember(ByVal newValue As String)
    m_someMember = newValue
End Property
```

---

> How to use it in standard module

```
Sub TypeTest()
    Dim x As SomeType
    x.SomeMember = "Hi"
    MsgBox x.SomeMember, vbInformation
End Sub

Sub ClassTest()
    Dim y As SomeClass
    Set y = New SomeClass
    y.SomeMember = "Hello"
    MsgBox y.SomeMember, vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the samples but as mentioned in my comments I'd like to avoid creating additional objects by using "static"/"shared" methods. But seems like this is not possible with classes or types.